# Limit Access to Outlook Contacts in Office 365

Tags: office365

We are starting to use Office 365 for students. Currently they can access any contact in the address book, including my own. Is there a way to limit their access to contacts? The only option I can find is to turn off access to contacts completely.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The answer I think to your question lies in something called Address Book Policies (ABP). You can use these to assign customer address lists to specific users.

I would suggest you take a look at the following;

http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2013/02/25/3552306.aspx - blog about ABP’s and O365.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh529948(v=exchg.150).aspx - ABP’s in Exchange Online, TechNet details.

Basically, create GAL's and AL's based on some kind of query/filter, and assign those to the students, so they can only see what you want them to see.

Greg